# QGIS 2.0 - can't select items in Print Composer

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, printing, print-composer

I am having an issue where I can create a print Layout in Print Composer, but once I have clicked away from an item (like map, legend, arrow, etc) I cannot select it again.

Comment: One possible reason you can't select again is if you've right-clicked to lock it. This will show as a red circle with diagonal bar. Right-click again to unlock.

Comment: I think I've encountered this problem once in 2.2. It might be a rare bug. If possible try the current test version 2.3 or the 2.4 release once it's out. Or file a bug report now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any bug here and three things spring to mind:

1. Make sure that the item you are trying to click on is not behind something else.  For instance, if your map or maybe a neatline surround the entire sheet (probably the largest element) is in front, then you will only be able to select that. Note what is selected and send big items to the back (see item 1 in picture below).  You may have to reorder a few items to get to the one you want.  Just keep clicking on the item you are trying to get to and look for the little blue selection makers at the corners of other items that might be overlaying it - then keep re-ordering until the one you want is at the top and can be selected.
2. Make sure you are in `Select/move item` mode (large blue arrow - see item '2' in picture below) and not `Move item content` mode (small green square with arrow next to item 2).  You use the latter to slide the map contents within the map frame but if it is still active then 
   you will not be able to select any elements.
3. Finally, if you right-clicked on the item at some point, it will be locked.  Locked items have a little blue padlock icon in the top left-hand corner and the cursor turns into a red 'No!' sign when you hover over the item.  Just right-click on a locked item to unlock it again.

[image]