# QGIS 2.2 Print Composer - pointer will not select or move items

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I refer to the questions at [QGIS 2.0 - can't select items in Print Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88865/qgis-2-0-cant-select-items-in-print-composer) and [QGIS 2.2 Print Composer does not display map with some datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97377/qgis-2-2-print-composer-is-not-working)

My question may be a duplicate, but the answer given in the first of those questions will not resolve the issue I am experiencing. If the CRS thing from the second one is a more likely cause, I would like a clear explanation.

I am using Windows 8.0 and the CRS of my map is EPSG 27700

It happens most often when I select my label, but it can be after selecting other items. Everything freezes on the layout - the selection pointer has no effect. I can add new items, but I can't move them or select anything else. I can select all or deselect all using the menu command, but still the pointer has no effect when clicked on the layout. I can lock and unlock using toolbar buttons, but not with a right click. I can use toolbar buttons to send selected items to back or front, but it makes no difference to the lack of pointer click functionality.

If I open a new print composer from my template, or if I close and re-open QGIS, the composer may work ok for a while, but then the same thing happens again. It was more intermittent, but today it is happening almost immediately every time.

I have disabled all my plug-ins, but it made no difference.

Comment: I think I've encountered this problem once in 2.2. It might be a rare bug. If possible try the current test version 2.3 or the 2.4 release once it's out. Or file a bug report now.

Comment: This should be fixed in the current nightly snapshots. Extra testing would be really appreciated though so we can be sure its fixed for 2.4.

Comment: @ndawson - Thanks. Composer from June 12th nightly build has been working fine for me for the past couple of days.